# JSTL loop as many time as EL variable says

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I need to convert this scriplet code into JSTL code, but I don't know how.

```
 <c:set var="HowManyTimesToLoop" value="${number}"/>
 <%
    int count = 1;
    int loop = (Integer) pageContext.getAttribute("HowManyTimesToLoop");

    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        out.println(count);
        count++;
     }
  %>
```

So I have ${number} variable which tells how many times I need to for-loop. Then I have a int variable count which goes from 1 to n where n is the ${number}.

I did it first with Java just to be clearer what I am looking for, but now I am struggling to do this in JSTL with EL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have this tag in your jsp: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
If you have already set HowManyTimesToLoop in pagecontext, then you can access it and iterate through the loop as:

```
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${HowManyTimesToLoop}">
       <c:out value="${i}"/>
    </c:forEach>
```